# How to print the characters in this output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash

It's always coming out 44 and it's not in order

Can you give me a hint of what I'm doing wrong? Or what can I do or study to fix it? What should I learn?
,<<

Comment: Have you tried changing the line with `print` so that it prints what you want instead of what it currently prints? What exactly was the difficulty?

Comment: It's always coming out 44 and it's not in order.I don't know how to print correctly

Comment: @mkrieger1 Look if the question became clearer now, edited.

Comment: The reason is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly. By `v[0] += 1` you are changing all elements of the list (because they are actually all the same element).

Comment: If you want to output the items in a specific order, you need to use the `sorted` function.

Answer (score 1):

```py
odernation = customHash(someSequence)

for codon, cnt in d.items():
    print('{}. {}: {}'.format(odernation,codon, cnt))
```

`odernation` is only being computed once and then being printed in the for loop. The value isn't changing.

Comment: how to make the value change?

Comment: Put it inside the for loop, so with every iteration, it'll calculate `odernation` again.